# JQuery Table post Calculate sum in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that contains Input text that calculate the sum of rows and the sum of coumns in JQuery.

Its posible to send the table in AJAX post to PHP and do the calc of rows and columns there?

This is my table:

```
<table id="sum_table">
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1" /></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum1"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum2"/></td>
        <td><input value="0" class="sum3"/></td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class ="totalCol">
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<button id="tabla">+</button>
<button id="moes">Hide/Show</button>
```

This is How I sum the columns:

```
//Mostramos y ocultamos la tabla
    $("#moes").click(function(){
         $("table").toggle();
   });

    //Sumamos las columnas
    $(document).on('keyup change','#sum_table tr:not(.totalCol) input:text',function() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    var total = 0;
    var thisNumber = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];


    $table.find('tr:not(.totalCol) .sum'+thisNumber).each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.value);
    });
```

[FULL CODE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ws6E8/)

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: set name of each input and serialize form (function called serialize() in js) and then unserialize it in PHP via function parse_str($_POST['serialized_values'], $result);
PS: Why do you need this table for ? :) It's kind of crazy :D And now i cannot think of any usage for it! :)

Comment: @Mr.TK hehe, I know its crazy but Im new in Jquery and I want to learn it good :P

Comment: Cool :) Good for You! Keep learning with passion and that will take You far!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tabla').click(function() {

       var col1 = [];
       var col2 = [];
       var col3 = [];

       // collect all data from table col1
       $.each($('table td input.sum1'), function(k, v){
           col1.push($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col2
       $.each($('table td input.sum2'), function(k, v){
           col2.push($(v).val());
       });

       // collect all data from table col3
       $.each($('table td input.sum3'), function(k, v){
           col3.push($(v).val());
       });

       // send data to server
       $.ajax({
           url: 'calc.php',
           type: 'post',
           data: {'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3': col3,},
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){

               // insert your server-calculated data to dom
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(1)').text(data.SumCol1);
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(2)').text(data.SumCol2);
               $('.totalCol td:nth-child(3)').text(data.SumCol3);
           }
       }); 
   });
});
```

You can sum up your posts on server in e.g. `calc.php`:

```
$SumCol1 = _sumUp($_POST['col1']);
$SumCol2 = _sumUp($_POST['col2']);
$SumCol3 = _sumUp($_POST['col3']);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "SumCol1" => $SumCol1, 
        "SumCol2" => $SumCol2, 
        "SumCol3" => $SumCol3
            ));

function _sumUp($data)
{
    $sum = 0;

    foreach($data as $k => $v)
    {
        $sum += $v;
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

NOTE: not tested. Only a basic structure.

Comment: Simon, this code should return me the total of all inputs?

Comment: @devtreat Now I have updated my code. Does completely fit to your table. I have tested it → works.

Comment: Im using your code but when return the values didnt insert them in totalCol it keep at 0

Comment: At first, please check your json response e.g. via FireBug. The JSON-response should have the following pattern: `{"SumCol1":369,"SumCol2":1368,"SumCol3":1361}`. At second, you should check your jQuery selectors regarding `.totalCol`. If you want to get secure, use ids on each total field (e.g. for html `<td id="totalCol1">0</td>` use jQuery `$('#totalCol1').text(data.SumCol1);`)

Comment: It send it Ok, I got this : col1[] 4
col1[] 2
col1[] 4
col2[] 5
col2[] 4
col2[] 3
col3[] 6
col3[] 5
col3[] 6
But in html nothing :/

Comment: I think that we have to put echo or something in PHP

Comment: @devtreat You´r right with echo. I used a Framework on server side. Updated.

Comment: Its possible, to create an array that have 3 arrays of every column, send it, calculate the sum of every column. And another array with 3 arrays one of every row , send it too and calculate the sum of rows?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51455/discussion-between-devtreat-and-simon-the-sourcecoderer)